# C++ vector initialization syntax inconsistencies

Tags: c++, xcode, vector, makefile, initialization

Using Xcode 6 or 7 on OS X Yosemite (fully patched), I have this line at file scope:

```
static const vector<uint8_t>addresses = vector<uint8_t>({0x10, 0x12, 0x73});
```

It compiles and executes fine as part of a cpp file. When I then create a makefile and try to build, I get 'error: expected expression' pointing at the left brace. I've played around with various syntax forms, and nothing works although the errors change. I've tried both g++ and clang as the compiler, to no effect.

Can anyone please suggest why this compiles and runs with Xcode, but not with a simple make? Better yet, what is it about the syntax I'm using that's not what it should be?

I've tried various language dialects as compiler options, but otherwise the makefile is purely using defaults.

Comment: you might need to enable c++11: -std=c++11

Comment: Side note, you can simply do: `static const vector<uint8_t>addresses {0x10, 0x12, 0x73};`.

Comment: What happens when you try to compile on the command line? If it works, then this is not an xcode problem; if it doesn't, then this is not a makefile problem.